# append carousel indicator jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, append, carousel

I.m using twitter bootstrap carousel to create a carousel of images. I need to add indicators to the carousel. The problem is that i am appending the carousel image divs using jquery append and this is causing the indicators to break. If i can append the indicators after appending the images I think i can solve the problem.  The images are being appended as follows.

```
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var $div = $('<div>').addClass('shop-image item')
              .css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] + ')');
              $('.carousel-inner').append($div);
        }
```

I need to append the following list items to my ordered list in the same manor. I have the ordered list in my html code i just need to add the list items.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

So basically i just dont know how to add data-target and data-slide-to using jquery append. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("element").attr("data-target", "your value");
```